# How to know the status of each process of one job in the slurm cluster manager?

Tags: cluster-computing, slurm

After using the [Slurm](https://slurm.schedmd.com/) cluster manager to sbatch a job with multiple processes, is there a way to know the status (running or finishing) of each process? Can it be implemented in a python script?

Comment: One way is login to the compute-node and use the regular Linux tools (`top`, `htop`, `ps`). Surely Python can wrap something.

Answer (score 3):

Just use the command [`sacct`](https://slurm.schedmd.com/sacct.html) that comes with Slurm.

Given this code (`my.sh`):

```
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH --nodes=1
#SBATCH --ntasks=2

srun -n1 sleep 10 &
srun -n1 sleep 3

wait
```

I run it:

```
sbatch my.sh
```

And then check on it with `sacct`:

```
sacct
```

Which gives me per-step info:

```
     JobID    JobName  Partition    Account  AllocCPUS      State ExitCode
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- --------
8021        my.sbatch    CLUSTER        me          2     RUNNING      0:0
8021.0          sleep                   me          1     RUNNING      0:0
8021.1          sleep                   me          1   COMPLETED      0:0
```

`sacct` has a lot of options to customize its output. For example,

```
sacct --format='JobID%6,State'
```

Will just give you the IDs (up to 6 characters) and the current state of jobs:

```
 JobID      State
------ ----------
  8021    RUNNING
8021.0    RUNNING
8021.1  COMPLETED
```

Answer (score 2):

If the processes you mention are distincts steps, then `sacct` can give you the information as explained by @Christopher Bottoms.

But if the processes are different tasks in a single step, then you can use [this script](https://github.com/OleHolmNielsen/Slurm_tools/blob/master/jobs/psjob) that uses parallel SSH to run 'ps' commands on the compute nodes and offer a summarised view, as @Tom de Geus suggests.